# From an included file, how can I get the filename of the file doing the including?

Tags: ruby

Apologies for the poorly worded question title - no idea how to put it better!

In the following code, when I execute `ruby bar.rb`, how can I make it output `bar.rb`, rather than `foo.rb`?

In `foo.rb`:

```
module Foo
  def filename
    __FILE__
  end
end
```

In `bar.rb`:

```
require_relative 'foo'
include Foo

puts filename # outputs 'foo.rb'
```

This is for a library function that, each time some code is executed, records the location (and git ref) of that code.

Comment: This is utterly hackish, but the [`caller`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-caller) method can get you some of the way there. `def filename; file = caller[0].split(':'); file[0]; end`.

Comment: hah :) I wouldn't be surprised if that was the only solution.

Comment: It may be, but it *still* feels hacky as hell. Having to parse the output that way is just foul. `caller` returns an array of strings, and the first part of each string is what you want. Depending on what you're doing, you may need to consider where in the stack you want to look though. That is, you may not always want the first entry in the array.

Comment: $0 is the name of the file used to start the program. so it will return the value of file_path.rb in ruby <file_path.rb>. Search for '$0' in http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/quickstart/4/

Comment: Use `caller` if you want to find the filename of the caller of the method. Use `$0` if you want to find the executable. Use `caller` inside `def self.included` if you want to find the filename when someone includes the module.

Comment: Seb:  this sounds like a bad design so maybe you should zoom out and tell us why you need to do this.  Could you not accomplish this with normal function calls?

Comment: fyi Sinatra does this looking for inline templates - stripping out all but application code - cf. [caller_files](https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1556) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question stimulated me to crack open the Ruby interpreter source and see how `__FILE__` actually works. The answer is pretty interesting: it's implemented right inside the parser. The lexer has a special token type for `__FILE__`. When the parser sees that token, it converts it to a string constant, which contains the name of the file the parser is working on.

From line 14948 of ext/ripper/ripper.c:

```
case keyword__FILE__:
return NEW_STR(rb_external_str_new_with_enc(ruby_sourcefile, strlen(ruby_sourcefile),
                        rb_filesystem_encoding()));
```

I think this should make it clear that trying to make `__FILE__` return the name of the including file is completely impossible, unless you hack the Ruby interpreter source, or write your own preprocessor which transforms `__FILE__` to something else before passing the Ruby source to the interpreter!

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick you might be a able to use. If you pass a block to the method you could use the blocks closure to determine it's source. Something like:

```
def filename(&blk)
  blk.eval "__FILE__"
end
```

But again, that means you have to pass a block.

Honestly I wonder what you are trying to accomplish, b/c outside of make some common core extension method, this is probably something you really don't want to do.